# auto transfer in solidity and smart contracts

Tags: smartcontracts

I need to have a smart contract that send's some percentage amount of incoming token to a wallet automatically to another wallet ,

for example my company has a wallet and I have another business partner
I want to share the profit of our business instantly when it comes to the company's wallet between me and my partner
is that technically possible to make an smart contract to do this transfers !?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way to implement this is through a smart contract, it is not possible to execute this rule directly in the wallets.

An example of how this can be done in solidity is using a smart contract which might look like this:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.9;

interface IERC20 {
function balanceOf(address who) external view returns (uint256);
function transfer(address to, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
function approve(address spender, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

contract MyVault {

address public yourWallet;
address public partnerWallet;
uint256 public partnerFee;

constructor(address _yourWallet, address _partnerWallet, uint256 _partnerFee) {
    yourWallet = _yourWallet;
    partnerWallet = _partnerWallet;
    partnerFee = _partnerFee;
}

function applyFee(address _coin, uint256 _quantity) public returns(bool) {
    IERC20 coinInstance = IERC20(_coin);
    require(coinInstance.allowance(msg.sender,address(this)) >= _quantity, "MyVault: not approved" );
    require(coinInstance.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _quantity), "MyVault: transfer from failed");
    uint256 partnerAmount = calculateFee(_quantity);
    coinInstance.transfer(partnerWallet, partnerAmount);
    coinInstance.transfer(yourWallet, _quantity - partnerAmount);
    return true;
}

function calculateFee(uint _value) public view returns(uint256) {
       return (partnerFee * _value) / 100;
   }

}
```